# Is there a way to load only part of an audio file to memory and not all of it? [Python]

Tags: python, audio, mp3

Opencv uses the VideoCapture object to read videos.

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture('/path/to/filename.mp4')
vid.set(0,time_we_want_in_milliseconds)
success,img = vid.read()
```

This way it doesn't load the entire video all at once but you can set the reader to a specific frame and read frames one by one.

Is there a way to do that for audio files?

So far in what I have found they load the entire audio file to memory and that takes time for large videos. For example the librosa library:

```
aud, _ = librosa.load('/path/to/audiofile.mp3', sr=fs)
```

Comment: Audio files contain bytes just like any other files. Have you looked into reading a preset amount of bytes from a file?

Comment: No I haven't actually. Can I do that and specify the exact samples of the audiostream to be read?

Comment: OpenCV doesn't care about audio... removed the tag